# Proper data fetching for ReactJS components and MobX

Tags: reactjs, mobx

What is the preferred way of data fetching (and posting) in MobX? Including the option for making spinners during onLoad of the external data call.

1. All using @actions in the store, making the components as dumb as possible, e.g. aim for as much stateless functional components as possible.
2. In the component, e.g. by using the ComponentDidMount or WillMount
3. By the use of Higher Order Components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [mobx documentation](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/action.html), actions should be done in mobx actions, so in stores as suggested by the first option you describe.

The example they provide fits quite exactly your use case:

```
@action    createRandomContact() {
    this.pendingRequestCount++;
    superagent
        .get('https://randomuser.me/api/')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .end(action("createRandomContact-callback", (error, results) => {
            // ^ Note: asynchronous callbacks are separate actions!
            if (error)
                console.error(error);
            else {
                const data = JSON.parse(results.text).results[0];
                const contact = new Contact(this, data.dob, data.name, data.login.username, data.picture)
                contact.addTag('random-user');
                this.contacts.push(contact);
                this.pendingRequestCount--;
            }
        }));
}
```